# How to open a UL as per table row button position in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table right now there are three rows with `Add Section` button (it may be increase). When i click on `Add Section` a `UL` is toggle, its working fine just for first row `Add Section`, when i click on second button then `UL` open with top button. how can i fix it?

In simple way, i want open `UL` as per button position. how can i do this with single `UL` list?

My Code:-

```js
$(function(){
            $('.add-section').click(function(){
                $('.section-area').toggle();
            });
        })
```

```css
.section-area{ background:#fff; padding: 5px; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px rgba(39, 59, 69, 0.4); width: 100px; position: absolute; top:61px; right:140px; display: none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
            <td><button class="add-section btn btn-primary">Add Section</button></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
            <td><button class="add-section btn btn-primary">Add Section</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
            <td><button class="add-section btn btn-primary">Add Section</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="section-area">
          <ul>
              <li>Add 1</li>
              <li>Add 2</li>
              <li>Add 3</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Comment: issue is your css brother.. defining absolute top and right

Comment: but i want as per button position  and buttons may be more than 100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem occurs because the `top` and `right` of your `section-area` are fixed. To fix that, simply change it so that the `top` and `right` change in accordance to which button is clicked. Here is a working example:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.add-section').click(function(){
        let buttonTopPosition = $(this).offset().top
        let buttonLeftPosition = $(this).offset().left
        let sectionAreaWidth = $(this).outerWidth()
        $('.section-area').toggle();
        $('.section-area').css({top: buttonTopPosition, left: buttonLeftPosition - sectionAreaWidth})
    });
})
```

```css
.section-area{
  background:#fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px rgba(39, 59, 69, 0.4);
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td><button class="add-section btn btn-primary">Add Section</button></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
      <td><button class="add-section btn btn-primary">Add Section</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
      <td><button class="add-section btn btn-primary">Add Section</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="section-area">
    <ul>
        <li>Add 1</li>
        <li>Add 2</li>
        <li>Add 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I changed your CSS `top` and `left` to be initially `0`. Then, I will update those properties when a button is clicked (updated using jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use the bootstrap dropdown for so many reasons:

1. your code is not well maintained for ex. when you click on the second row you if the dropdown is already opened you have to click two times.
2. there no indication that this is a drop down.
3. styles are not well prepared.

You don't need to reinvent the wheel you are using the bootstrap so try to use it as much as you can.

**Check the snippet:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Add Section
        </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
      <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Add Section
        </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
      <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Add Section
        </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> [image: Upvote if you like it]